# Нужно разделить строку на столбцы postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Народ, только начал изучать SQL. Нужно разделить строку на два столбца по делителю. Есть email, делитель @, нужно создать столбцы со значениями до знака и после знака. я нашел только вариант до знака функция Split_part, но она работает только слева на право, а вот как быть справа на лево, ума не приложу

````
     ```
     SELECT customer_id, email, 
     SPLIT_PART(email, '@', 1) AS email_before
     FROM customer
     ```
````

Comment: [split_part — Разделяет строку string по символу delimiter и возвращает элемент по заданному номеру (считая с 1)](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgrespro/9.6/functions-string)

Comment: `SPLIT_PART(email, '@', 1) AS email_before, SPLIT_PART(email, '@', 2) AS email_after`

Comment: От души, спасибо большое